# Adding value to arrayList when actionListener is called?

Tags: java

What I need to happen is when the user inputs text into a JTextField and then 'Enter' is pressed, that text is added to an arraylist. What actually happens is no data is added to arraylist. Here some code below.

```
public class browser extends JFrame{
public boolean actionState = false;
private JPanel panel;
protected JTextField field;

public browser(){
   panel = new JPanel();
   field = new JTextField("Enter a URL"); 
   panel.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   actionListenerCalls();
}

private void actionListenerCalls(){

        //action performed when user types url into input box and presses Enter key
        field.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        loadData(e.getActionCommand());
                        actionState = true;
                        }
                    }
                );
    }
```

Inside of another class I have the arraylist. When actionSate becomes true the addURL() method should be called.

```
private ArrayList<String> array new ArrayList<String> ();

    //constructor
    public buttons(){
        if(actionState == true || hyperlinkState == true){
             addURL(field);
            System.out.println("URL added");
         }
    }

    //method for adding text inside of field to arraylist
    public void addURL(JTextField field){
     array.add(field.getText());
    }
```

Constructor browser and buttons are called inside of another class.

```
public class readFile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        browser file = new browser();
        file.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        buttons b = new buttons();


    }
}
```

Comment: Did u check actionState or hyperlinkState true. Or both false

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a **working** code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. For instance, we can't even see where the `buttons` class is being constructed (note: Java classes should be `TitleCase`).

Comment: Please show when the constructor `buttons` is called.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise `array` before using it

try

```
private ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm concerned by your wording:

> When actionSate **becomes** true the `addURL()` method should be called.

Do you realise that this `if` statement is evaluated just once, when the constructor is called?

```
//constructor
public buttons(){
    if(actionState == true || hyperlinkState == true){ // <-- only evaluated once
         addURL(field);
        System.out.println("URL added");
     }
}
```

If `actionState` becomes true at a later time, the `addURL()` method will **not** be called.

It's not clear from your code example whether you are even calling this constructor. Possible you are calling it in the `loadData()` method. However, since the last action of your action listener is to set `actionState` to true, there is no chance that your `addURL()` method is being called.

#### Solution?

You probably need to directly invoke the `addURL()` method from your action listener method. Ensure your action listener class has a reference to an instance of your `Buttons` class, then it can invoke the method directly. E.g.

```
public class Foo {

  // private boolean actionState = false; remove this?
  private Buttons buttons;

  public Foo(Buttons buttons) {
    this.buttons = buttons;
  }

  private void actionListenerCalls(){

    //action performed when user types url into input box and presses Enter key
    field.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          loadData(e.getActionCommand());
          buttons.addURL((JTextField) e.getSource());
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @user3593948: you can solve this (for example) by passing an instance of your class to the actionlistener and calling some method on this instance so that you enforce the check to be made again